# How to give numbers to vertical line in HTML and CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to create Y-axis like line in HTML and CSS. I want this line should look like Y-axis only.

I tried the following approach. It is working as per my expectation but it doesn't look good.

```css
#mySpan{
  writing-mode: vertical-lr; 
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<table >
    <tr>
    <td><span style="writing-mode: vertical-lr; 
        transform: rotate(180deg);"> <b>Secondary Axis</b></span></td>
    <td>
    <ul>
    <br><br><br>
        <li>3</li><br><br><br><br>
        <li>2</li><br><br><br><br>
        <li>1</li><br><br><br><br>
        <li> 0</li><br><br><br><br>
        </ul>
    </td>
    <td> 
        <div  style="border-left: 1px solid black; height:250px;position:left;left: 50%;">            
        </div> 
     </td>


    </tr>
</table>
```

Also it is consuming space in the top or bottom. May be it is because I have used  `br`    tag.

Does anyone suggest what changes/modification I need to do, so that it looks like Y-Axis.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is the way you can create it,
Use `display: flex;` on parent to make child flexible

`flex-direction: column;` to show items in a column, if you will not give this then items will appear on single line like X asix.

`justify-content: space-between;` to devide the equal gap between items

Note: You can increase and decrease the numbers in LI, they will auto adjust.

```css
.wrapper {display: flex;}
ul {list-style:none; height: 250px; display: flex; flex-direction: column; justify-content: space-between; border-right: 1px solid; }
li {
text-align:right;
position: relative;
padding-right: 5px;
}
li:after {
content: "-";
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
right: 0;
transform: translate(60%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<ul>
  <li>0.0005</li>
  <li>13</li>
  <li>12.44</li>
  
  <li>1</li>
  <li>.100</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: This is perfectly working as per my requirement. Some silly questions I have. 
1. For more than 2 digits it is overlapping with "-".
2. Is it possible to create "li" dynamically as per the input. 
This might be a silly questions but I am new in FE .  

Thanks

Comment: I didnt get yor 2nd point,
Is it possible to create "li" dynamically as per the input

Comment: fixed it for 1st point, if this helps you , don't forget to mark this as a right answer

Comment: is it possible that If I passed 4 items then it should create 4 <li> tag , if 3 then 3 <li> tags. I hope I am clear now.

Comment: Yes second point is working. Could u please also check for 4-5 digit. because some time the values might be 0.0005 ,0.045 etc. then it will be overlap.

Comment: could you please help me with one point here is. In case of browser adjustment the line is getting shrink and similar case with zoom out/In. could you please check and suggest change please.

Comment: Let me fix it for you

Comment: now you can add digit of any length, if this helps you, don't forget to mark it as right answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are a lot of mistakes in your code..
The space problem is because your 
The second problem is because you have used the vertical line as div with height style (you can enlarge the 250px (to catch the 
 you have added))

in button line, if you planning to use this for adding formula or something this will not work for you.

start with html canvas or svg

Answer (score 0):

```css
ul {
  list-style:none;
  border-right: 1px solid;
  width: 20px;
}

li {
  margin-bottom: 125px
}

li:after {
  content: "-";
  padding-left: 9px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>0</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Pseudo elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements) and [CSS counters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Lists_and_Counters/Using_CSS_counters)

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin:0;
}
body{padding: 6rem}
ul{
    position: relative;
    counter-reset: timeline-counter -1;
    border-left: 1px solid black; 
    
    transform: scale(-1) rotateY(180deg);
}

ul li{
    position: relative;
    counter-increment: timeline-counter; 
    height: 32px;
    color: white;
    background-color: grey;
    margin-bottom: 1rem; 
    list-style: none;
    transform:rotateX(180deg);
    line-height: 32px;
    padding-left: 1rem
} 

ul li:before { 
    content: "0" counter(timeline-counter); 
    position: absolute;
    top: 8px; 
    left: -32px;
    font-size: 1rem;
    color: black;
    line-height: 1;
}
ul li:after {
    content: "";
    --height-lenght: 1px;
    position: absolute;
    top: calc(50% - var(--height-lenght));
    left: -6px;
    width: 12px;
    height: var(--height-lenght);
    background-color: hsl(0deg 0% 0%);
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Line 1</li>
  <li>Line 2</li>
  <li>Line 3</li>
  <li>Line 4</li>
  <li>Line 5</li>
  <li>Line 6</li>
</ul>
```

Or using [flex box](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-direction)

```css
    *{
      box-sizing: border-box;
      padding: 0;
      margin:0;
    }
    body{padding: 6rem}
    ul{
        position: relative;
        counter-reset: timeline-counter -1;
        border-left: 1px solid black;  
        flex-direction: column-reverse;
        display: flex;
    }

    ul li{
        position: relative;
        counter-increment: timeline-counter; 
        height: 32px;
        color: white;
        background-color: grey;
        margin-bottom: 1rem; 
        list-style: none; 
        padding-left: 1rem; 
        line-height: 32px;
    } 

    ul li:before { 
        content: "0" counter(timeline-counter); 
        position: absolute;
        top: 8px; 
        left: -32px;
        font-size: 1rem;
        color: black;
        line-height: 1;
    }
    ul li:after {
        content: "";
        --height-lenght: 1px;
        position: absolute;
        top: calc(50% - var(--height-lenght));
        left: -6px;
        width: 12px;
        height: var(--height-lenght);
        background-color: hsl(0deg 0% 0%);
    }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Line 1</li>
  <li>Line 2</li>
  <li>Line 3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @Glidas.Tambo When browser is getting zoom In/out the vertical line is also shrinking and increasing. I want the height of line should be fixed. What change do I need in above code. Please suggest

Comment: @Kim that is strange i don't have the same effect as you. can you please give me the name of your browser and the version number if possible ? and by the way which on of the sample above? or you mean both of them

Comment: I am using chrome Version 90.0.4430.93. and both are behaving same. I tried on firefox 88.0.1 as well but same issue

Comment: Very Strange do you have `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">` in your head? I have the same version but i'm not getting that issue. If possible share you screen with me.

Comment: I got it.  when I am doing zoom In/out then my table is adjusting and accordingly this vertical line is also adjusting. I need to look at this table adjustment. Can we explicilty give height to this vertical line ?

Comment: @Kim Yes you can, the height of the vertical line ist the height of the `ul` element, so it can be fixed or dynamic depending on your goal. Note that the line is just the `border-left` of the `ul` element.